# How can I remove ".._.iTunes Preferences.plist.*" files?

Tags: macos, itunes

I have around 2,000 files that look like ".._.iTunes Preferences.plist.XXXXXX". I've tried to remove them with:

```
find . -name ".._*" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

But, the files are still there. How can I get rid of these files?

Comment: Sidenote: you shouldn't use `-exec rm -f {} \;`, just use `-delete` to remove matching files.

Comment: I tried that and it has the same `No such file or directory` error as when you do a `rm`. This error was one of the reasons I tried to do a different way of deleting these files. But, thank you for letting me know about the `--delete` option.

Comment: Do a file system check using Disk Utility: Select the partition the files are on and "Verify Disk". It sounds like there's something wrong there.

Comment: Daniel, Verify/Repair Disk is the answer. After doing that, the files were easily removed. If you list this as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it as correct. Thank you!

Comment: [That won't send a notification](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), but something like @DanielBeck would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they're all in the same directory, use

```
rm ./.._.iTunes*
```

---

Your comment suggests that something's wrong with the file system. Try to repair it using Disk Utility.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this does not work. It says "rm: ./.._.iTunes Preferences.plist.wMrHGd: No such file or directory" for every file.